# Connect three HDMI TV to MacBookPro

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, macbook, hdmi, firewire

I have a presentation I don't have my HP notebook with my so I'm stuck with MacBookPro 5.5

It has one Firewire port. I need to connect 3 TVs to and I would need to play a different video on each. Basically I would have my notebooks desktop extended 3 times and then a VLC Player instance on each screen playing one video.

What do I need to do this. All I found for Mac was an HDMI Hub option that has one HDMI hub input and 4 HDMI outputs but that does not allow you to extend your desktop I believe that is the HDMI hub that they use in tech stores where they connect all the TVs to the Hub and then play one video from a PC and it outputs to all.

So what do I need to connect 3 TV's to my MacBookPro 5.5

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you are out of luck.  The only port you have with enough bandwidth for streaming video is the mini-DisplayPort, and with DisplayPort 1.1 it isn't enough for 3 screens.  If you had a newer MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt it should be possible.  Or if you wanted to display slowly changing screens such as PowerPoint there are USB video adapters, but they can't keep up with streaming video.

---

A newer laptop with DisplayPort 1.2 would support "Multi-Stream Transport".  For more information, see

- http://www.wsgf.org/blog/skipclarke/2013/01/04/2013-year-displayport-mst
- http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/UsingaBizLinkDisplayPortMulti-StreamTransportHub.aspx

Comment: My MacBookPro 5.5 is 2009~ model how do I check if it has Thunderbolt connector ? What if I used my HP Notebook ATI 6770HD Mobile 1GB dedicated RAM with HDMI output, 12GB RAM, QuadCore. Would this give me more options ?

Comment: Also if I have a Thunderbolt connector how would I do it then ?

Comment: I checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Second_generation_.28unibody.29) when posting my answer.  There's no Thunderbolt on your model.  If your HP has USB 3.0 or an ExpressCard slot you may have more options... but the limiting factor isn't CPU speed or GPU speed, it's the throughput of outputs able to carry video data.

Comment: @kellax: See edit concerning connection of multiple displays through one DisplayPort

Answer (score 0):

Here's Apple's official response to connecting multiple displays to your Mac. I understnad that this isn't a direct answer to your question but may be a good resource for you none the less.

[How to use multiple displays with your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5019)

Here's a link to someone who has 4 monitors connected to their Macbook that may be of use to you as well.

[My MacBook Pro Goes Multimonitor: 4 Monitors At Once!](http://daggle.com/macbook-pro-multimonitor-4-monitors-at-once-1577)